# ¿Por que no funciona al sumar los valores de una columna de una tabla? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sumatoria

Lo que quiero es sumar todos los valores de una columna `price` y poder mostrarlos donde dice total.

Pero con el código que tengo solo me arroja el valor cero y no me hace la suma. ¿Alguno me puede ayudar con la formula que tendría que hacer para poder mostrar eso?

El campo `price` esta en la tabla `products` y lo que deseo es sumar los valores la columna `price`

```
        
        
        $data =Product::select('products.*','users.name as s_name')
        ->join('users','products.id_seller','=','users.id')
        ->where('products.id_subasta',$id)
        ->get();
        $all=[];
        $vendidos = 0;
        $noVendidos =0;
        $total=0;
        foreach($data as $d){
             $buyer=Sell::select('sells.price','users.name','users.phone','users.address',
                'buyers.number','buyers.credit','sells.id as id_sell')
                
                ->join('buyers','sells.id_buyer','=','buyers.id')
                ->join('users','buyers.id_user','=','users.id')
                ->where('sells.id_product',$d->id)
                ->first();
                if($d->status == 0){
                    $vendidos+=1;
                   
                }else{
                    $noVendidos+=1;
                }
            $all[]=[
                'id'=>$d->id,
                'product'=>$d,
                'buyer'=>$buyer,
               'price'=>$d->price,
            ];$total+=$d->price ;
        } 
        $data[]=[
                
                'total'=>$total,
              
            ];
        
        $sub = Subasta::find($id);
        $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.products', [
            'img'=>$this->getLogo(),
            'data'=>$all,
            'subasta'=>$sub,
            'vendidos'=>$vendidos,
            'noVendidos'=>$noVendidos,
            'total'=>$total,
           
          

        ]);
        //$_ENV['key'] = 'value';
        return $pdf->stream();
```

Desconozco el código que tengo que poner ¿Cómo debería escribir el código?

Sé que para la mayoría será muy fácil mi pregunta, estoy aprendiendo :) gracias de antemano.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wu7u.png
aquí me arroja el resultado en 0
Ahí esta la imagen, quiero el resultado de la columna PRICE, quisiera saber como sumar todos los datos de una columna de mi base de datos.

Comment: El total lo incrementas fuera del ciclo. Te conviene revisar el log.

Answer (score 1):

Estas intentado sumar a `$total` el `$d->price` fuera del buble `foreach` y por eso te da cero.

#### Solución:

Solo tenes que mover esa línea dentro del `foreach`

```php
// código anterior
foreach ($data as $d) {
    // mas código

    $total += $d->price;
}
// resto del código
```

---

Para poder encontrar este tipo de errores más rápido, te recomiendo:

- Configurar [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) correctamente.

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL); // ejemplo
  ```
- Activar [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

  ```
  ini_set("display_errors", 1); // ejemplo
  ```

Comment: me sigue saliendo 0

Comment: @JAPLOR, seguro que hiciste el cambio, guardaste y recargaste? no tendrás cache y continuas visualizando un PDF viejo?

Comment: ya elimine cache y me sale Undefined variable `$total` al querer imprimir

Comment: actualiza el post con los cambios que has hecho al codigo y el error que te sale y en que linea sale ... entre mas informacion nos des mas facil es darte una respuesta.

Comment: listo nomas cambie `$total += $d->price;` adentro del `foreach`  me sale Undefined variable $total al querer imprimir

Comment: @JAPLOR, es raro que antes te diera cero y que ahora `undefined`. Será que modificaste la vista `pdf.products`? Por que la variable está definida inicialmente en cero.